# detekt - How to change function naming rule?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, detekt

I want to modify the rules of naming function because I am working on a project Android with Compose, and need a function starting with upper-case.
Current condition:

```
@Compossable
fun SomeScreen() {} // violate naming function
```

The warning message:

```
Warning:(26, 5) detekt - FunctionNaming: Function names should match the pattern: [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I already create file detekt.yml and add it to configuration file, but still not working. here is my detekt configuration detekt.yml:

```
FunctionNaming:
    active: true
    functionPattern: '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
```

and this is configuration in my Android Studio

[image]

Comment: Are you invoking detekt solely from your IDE or are you getting the warning when running the gradle detekt task? If you're having detekt configured using gradle, could you share your configuration?

Comment: hi @greyhairredbear, I install detekt from IDE. Install via market place in the IDE

Comment: Yet another question: is that your complete detekt.yml file?

Comment: Further, from your answer, I take the error message you see is within the IDE, is that correct? Just wanted to ensure that there is no gradle config that you are missing in case the error is shown when using detekt with the gradle plugin.

Comment: hi @greyhairredbear, yes that is complete of my detekt.yml. and the second question also correct, that is error message from my IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case that really is your entire configuration file, you are missing the ruleset element before the rule element itself:

```
naming:
  active: true
  FunctionNaming:
    active: true
    functionPattern: '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
```